# Decrypt a JWE using list of keys that are stored in DB using JAVA 8 Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I Have a JWE which is to be decrypted using list of keys stored in DB. I have to try each key until I find the one that actually decrypts.

I am trying to do it in JAVA 8 way, writing Lambdas But I am  unable to understand how to do it.

I have written following code

```
List<String> listKeys = myMapper.getDistinctEncKeyIds().stream()                .map(MyMapper::encrypTionIdsfromDbData).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This gives me list of keys and I am writing normal java code

```
for(int i=0; i<listKeys.size();i++) {
            try {
                decryptedToken=  decrypt(token,listKeys.get(i));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                log.info("key not found: %s", e);
            }
        }
```

I want to convert it into JAVA 8 lambda code because that takes less no of lines and is easier to use something like this

```
myMapper.getDistinctEncKeyIds().stream()
                .map(myMapper::encrypTionIdsfromDbData)
                .filter(key-> decrypt(token,key))
                .findFirst();
```

But I have two issues here

1. Decrypt Method actually returns a key and filter takes a method which returns a boolean
2. Decrypt method throws JOSEException, again I get an error in filter and I have to write try/catch block in the lambda

My Aim is to find the key that actually decrypts this token and return that key. I am not getting how to write it in java 8. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `decrypt` return when it cannot decrypt a key?

Comment: I run decrypt(token,key) in a loop passing each key and it returns the key which decrypts. This logic works fine. My question is hot to call decrypt after getting the keys in this lambda and return the key which has decrypted it. "myMapper.getDistinctEncKeyIds().stream()
                .map(myMapper::encrypTionIdsfromDbData) "

Comment: Your imperative style of writing the code is also incomplete in terms of the final operation and initial assignments if there are any. Due to which the question is quite unclear imho.